# hugo-academic theme in blogdown: how to always show social/academic icons on about widget

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I was able to create a (static) web site with blogdown R package using hugo-academic theme. I have also customised several things around, but I'm struggling with a couple of points I'm not able to solve. 
The social/academic icons related to Twitter, GoogleScholar, ResearchGate, etc. are shown on the about widget below the organization but only on phone/tablet browsers and not on Desktop. I would like to have them always shown.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, check the CSS files in the hugo-academic theme. It's possible the social media icons have some media queries applied to them, making them only show up on tablets.

Comment: I checked the demo available at https://sourcethemes.com/academic/ and the same behaviour is present on my old MacBookPro (1280x800 display) when using Safari, but it is ok with Google Chrome. On iPhone, iPad and iMac social/academic icons are always visible. Definitely, there is something related with CSS or with Safari but I'm not able to figure out. Since it seems a more general problem I have open an issue on GitHub repo for the project.